# List Separators with Hidden Element

Tags: css

I have a List like this (assume it's dynamic):

A | B | C

But I want it to show only the inner separators no matter how many elements it has:

A | B

A | B | C | D | E

This works with this sample

https://jsfiddle.net/ggL4z0uv/

```
<div class="toolbar">
  <div class="button">
  A
  </div>
  <div class="button">
  B
  </div>
  <div class="button">
  C
  </div>
</div>
```

And here the relevant css:

```
.toolbar .button:after {
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    height: 17px;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.toolbar .button:first-child:after {
  border-right: 0px;
}

.toolbar .button.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

However, if I add the hide class to the first element, I get an extra border which I do not need.

| B | C

Is there a nice way to solve this with css? I need to be able to hide the elements with `display:none`...

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Code added. However, I still see the question as a valid one that makes sense, don't see why it is being downvoted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are complicating the things and make hard your own job. You don't need `button:after` pseudoclass to put only a border, just add the border to the buttons

https://jsfiddle.net/ggL4z0uv/1/

```
 .toolbar .button {
      border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
 }
```

And remove the `button:after` pseudo.

That's all!

### EDIT

I read your comment and I made a simple change to achieve that you exactly need:

https://jsfiddle.net/ggL4z0uv/4/

.toolbar .button:last-child {
      border-right: 0;
   }

Thanks to the changes at the start of this answer, this is a very easy change to achieve the following behaviour:

`A | B | C`

`B | C`

Please, tell us if this solves your problem.

Comment: Sorry, but this is precicely the problem, Your approach always shows the extra separator at the end. I'm hoping for no separators at the beginning nor at the end...

Comment: I undestand your following words: `However, if I add the hide class to the first element, I get an extra border which I do not need. | B | C`. I will read carefully the post to view the problem deeply

Comment: Well, I edit the post, with my changes in this answer it is very easy to achieve that you need